# Getting the largest value from an array

Tags: java

I have values{42_2,42_3,43_1,43_2,44_1,44_2,44_3} in an ArrayList in java.
I want to fetch only these values (42_3,43_2,44_3) from my array.
How can I do that?

My code:

```
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<(Arrays.asList("42_1","42_2","43_1","43_2","44_1"‌​,"44_2","44_3")); 
for (String y : x) { 
     String[] no=y.split("_"); 
     for (int index = 0; index < no.length; index++) { 
          if (no[index] == no[1]){ 
              b.add(no[0]); 
          } 
      } 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried splitting the value using "_" and then comparing but i am not getting the result

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("42_1","42_2","43_1","43_2","44_1","44_2","44_3"));

  for (String y : x) {

   String[]  no=y.split("_");

   for (int index = 0; index < no.length; index++)
   {

    if ( no[index] == no[1] ){

     b.add(no[0]);

    }
   }
  }

Comment: I tried this but i am not getting the idea how to proceed further

Comment: @RahulGupta Post your code and clarifications as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: Hashmap <double, string> ---- 42.1, 42_1     find the highest key and print it's value.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> yourList = Arrays.asList("42_2", "42_3", "43_1", "43_2", "44_1", "44_2", "44_3");
    List<String> targetList = new ArrayList();
    String currentFirstPart = null;
    String actualMax = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++) {
        String current = yourList.get(i);
        final String[] token = current.split("_");
        String firstPart = token[0];

        // only the first iteration 
        if (currentFirstPart == null) {
           currentFirstPart = firstPart;
        }

        // we add the element when the first part of the String changes
        // and we reset the actualMax
        else if (!firstPart.equals(currentFirstPart)) {
          targetList.add(actualMax);
          actualMax = null;
          currentFirstPart = firstPart;
        }

        // we update the actual max for the current first part
       if (actualMax == null || current.compareTo(actualMax) >= 1) {
           actualMax = current;
         }
    }
    // We add the last element here if not added in the loop
    if (currentFirstPart != null) {
        targetList.add(actualMax);
    }
  }
```

Comment: But if i am having only {42_1,43_1,44_2} and i want to retrieve them as they largest in their value, i am not gettingn the result

Comment: You are welcome :) I coded what you have initially asked. You would have specified more precisely your need. You should open  a new question by being clear about your requirement. Besides, if my answer has addressed your initial question, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define the criteria what is larger than what. You basically got an arraylist of strings.
Why is 42_3 larger than 44_2?

(this answer could be a comment if stackoverflow would allow me)

Comment: Actually I want highest valuewith particular number. For eg : Among 42_2, 42_3 42_3 is bigger similarly for 43_2 and 44_3